Как исправить в phpMyAdmin следующую ошибку?
Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Появляются такие ошибки после создания таблицы, связанные с версией PHP.

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение

Установи свежую версию ПМА.
